# String formatting fails when named formatters are found

Tags: string, powershell

Why formatting below string fails when trying to pass value for numbered parameter

This fails
`v1/acknowledge/{requestUuid}/{registrationUuid}/response?requestUuid={0}&registrationUuid={1} -f "a","b"`

This works

`v1/acknowledge/requestUuid/registrationUuid/response?requestUuid={0}&registrationUuid={1} -f "a","b"`

This is the cause of error

> {requestUuid}/{registrationUuid}

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To escape curly brackets in a formatted string you will need to use double curly brackets like:

```
'v1/acknowledge/{{requestUuid}}/{{registrationUuid}}/response?requestUuid={0}&registrationUuid={1}' -f 'a', 'b'
```

This counts for **PowerShell** and for [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) in **C#**.
The differs in PowerShell is that named placeholders are not (yet) supported in PowerShell, see: [adding Named placeholders in format operator](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12374)

Comment: I am not trying to use placeholder here. These are actual string that I don't want to replace. I just want to replace {0}, {1} only